# how to assign selected value to variable

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

Sorry for kinda begginer's question, but I am stuck, so any help is appreciated.

So, I am trying to display election results on map, and it works as separate static script, but when I try to integrate it into shiny and make it input-dependent, it doesn't work:

```
            selectInput("selected", 
                        label = "Show me:", 
                        drop_down_menu, 
                        selected = drop_down_menu[1]))

    #later on, in "server"part, why selected values can't directly be assigned to variable?

    #direct assign works 
    active_filter <- drop_down_menu[1]

    #but assigning of selected value does not
    active_filter <- Input$selected
```

the whole app is on https://github.com/deksterica/R/blob/master/proba1

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Do you define `Input` (upper-case "i"), or is that a typo? (2) The `input$` variables are *reactive*, meaning they cannot be accessed where you are trying, it must instead be inside a `reactive` or `observe` (or some other reactive) block.

Comment: The scope of the variable 'drop_down_menu' is Global as you have assigned this variable outside the app code. That is why you can use it anywhere in the app. All the input variables are reactive in nature so you cannot assign inputs outside the render, reactive or observe functions.

Comment: @TimsySuri, r2evans, thank you both so much, the concept of global-reactive variables is now clear